# how to provide list of sheets of file in combo box?

Tags: c#

I have to load excel file into sql server i use window application so i select filepath in textbox when click button using fileopendialogbox my problem is that i want ot provide list of sheets of file in combo box.

so user can select appropriate sheet to upload. Because it may possible that there are many sheets in file and tool doesn’t know which one to upload.

Comment: What are "sheets of file"? I have never heard this expression before.

Comment: I think the OP means to be able to select between different 'sheet's in an Excel file. Remember you can have more than one sheet in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
  this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xls";
  if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(
         openFileDialog1.FileName, 0, true, 5,
          "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false,
          0, true); 
     Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
     list.Add (sheets);
   }
```